# Sharing React Component props with grandchildren components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Im struggling to figure out how to share props with grandchildren of a component in react/typescript. Why is the constructer props getting overwritten?

```
class Resource extends Component<IResourceProps, IResourceState> {

  state:IResourceState = {

  }

  _finder: new this.props.finder({api: this.props.api})

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path={this.props.path} component={() => {return this._finder}} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Resource;
```

```
class UserFinder extends React.Component<IResourceFinderProps, IResourceFinderState> implements IResourceFinder {

    _data:  any[] = []

    load = (response: QueryResponse): void => {
        this._data = response.records;
    }

    constructor(props:IResourceFinderProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.api.query({  //<-------- this.props.api is undefined! Why?
            page: 0,
            pageSize: 100
          }, (response:QueryResponse) => {
              this.load(response);
        })
    }

    render() {
        const columns = [
            {
                title: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'firstName',
                key: 'firstName'
            }
        ];
        return (
            <div>
                <Table columns={columns} rowKey="userId" dataSource={this._data} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default UserFinder
```

App.js

```
<Route  path="/users" finder={UserFinder} api={this.api} />
```

Essentially, I want to share the api prop with all of the children of the Route without having to explicitly set it on each one individually. Perhaps, another solution could be giving the child a reference to the grandparent somehow. What are some of my options?

Answer (score 2):

First, if you just want to pass props through the Router, use the prop `render` instead of `component`. E.g.:

```
<Route path={this.props.path} render={(props) => <Component {...props} additionalProps={...} />} />
```

If you really want to share state without passing props, you will need something like a global state. There, you have different options.

- The formerly most used was redux (see [docs](https://redux.js.org/) and well known [tutorial](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) ).
- With the React update and the support of hooks, there are simpler ways to build such a global state system. You could build it from scratch with `useContext` & `useReducer` like [this](https://dev.to/vanderleisilva/global-state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-5f6h)
- Or you could just use `ReactN` which gives you a global state out of the box (see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactn))

Comment: I was also going to suggest global state / a store. In addition to what Mika said, MobX is pretty easy to use.